# Can two chromosome with different size have single-pint crossover?

Tags: machine-learning, genetic-algorithm

I was working in Genetic Algorithm. I have a doubt as bellow:
Say I have two chromosome with different size as bellow:
1234567
ABCDEFGHIJ

Is it possible to have single point crossover as bellow:

123|4567

ABC|DEFGHIJ

=>

123DEFGHIJ

ABC4567

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your domain. GA often operates on fixed-length genotypes, but your domain apparently requires variable length genotypes.

Single point crossover is perfectly applicable to variable length genotypes. You choose a random split-point in the first genotype, another random split-point in the second genotype, then you swap the parts and get two new genotypes.

```
Parents:
     123|4567
ABCDEFGH|IJ

Children:
     123|IJ
ABCDEFGH|4567
```

Answer (score 0):

If your algorihm/domain needs/can have variable-length genotype then yes, it definitely is possible. It is the default in e.g. Grammatical Evolution (it's a GP algorithm but uses linear binary genotypes and GA-like operators).